# 401 Unauthorized when trying to logout from Loopback's built in user management

Tags: express, authentication, loopbackjs, loopback

I followed the steps found at the https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Logging-in-users.html tutorial.

I am able to log-in correctly and I am given a unique Access Token, however logout throws a "401 Unauthorized". The headers contain the access token that I was given.

How can I logout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. The issue was 'body-parser' configuration issue. The server.js should look like:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); //Configure body parser
app.use(loopback.token()); //Use access tokens
```

If you extend from the user-management example it will be already configured. Blank applications do not include this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try this [link](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/user-based-authentication-with-loopback/). Goto section **Extending Login/Logout from the Built-in User Model**.

This method solves a lot of problem like custom logic for `loginAttempts`, `loginAccess` etc..

Hope this helps.